# Creating a Text String from a Dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to create a text string from a dataframe, but specify which rows will add to the text string.

Here is an example dataframe:

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 2))
x$V1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 2)
x$V2 <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", 1)
x$V3 <- c(1, 2, 3, NA
```

I only want to build the text strings where `x$V1 = 1`.
The result I am looking for is something like `"aa 1 bb 2 cc 3"`, where the row where `x$V1 = 2` is ignored for the building of the text string.

I have tried the following:

```
x$V4 <- for(i in 1:length(x$V1)){
  if (x[i, 1] == 1){
    paste(x[i,2], x[i,3])
  } else {""}
}
paste(x$V3, collapse = "")
```

The above code does not even create a `V4` column in my dataframe.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What should the new column look like? That same string repeated three times, then `NA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` to do this. In general you can't assign from a `for` loop in the way you are attempting to do; you should assign from inside the loop. But it is much better to avoid loops.

```r
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 2))
x$V1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 2)
x$V2 <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", 1)
x$V3 <- c(1, 2, 3, NA)

x$V4 = ifelse(x$V1 == 1, paste(x$V2, x$V3), "")
paste(x$V4, collapse = " ")
#> [1] "aa 1 bb 2 cc 3 "
```

Created on 2018-10-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one line solution using base R -

```
do.call(paste, c(x[x$V1 == 1, -1], collapse = " "))

[1] "aa 1 bb 2 cc 3"
```